# Assign a template from a place other than local.xml

Tags: template, router, action

I'm creating a custom page for some categories, I'm filtering the different blocks that I need to use in the catalog/category/view.phtml, but in some categories I wanna use a template with 1 column, and others to use 2 columns.

Can I assign or change the template to use from router class? or some other place ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post some example code

Comment: I think I just need to know if is possible change the template from the route,